# spring.cloud.vault.config.lifecycle.enabled not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, spring-vault

Spring cloud vault keeps trying to renew token but I want to forbid it from doing so. When I was using spring 2.3.x I could just set `spring.cloud.vault.config.lifecycle.enabled=false` but it does not seem to work in 2.4.x, how can I solve this problem?

I have tried to custom `VaultConfig` and set token-supplier to `path.to.vaultconfig`.